# Swift creating a custom Alert Controller initializer

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I am working on implementing a UIAlertController for a confirmation when reseting a users password. I created a custom class that inherits from the UIAlertController. I also made the init for the class that I saw in the documentation.

```
import UIKit

class PasswordResetConfirmationViewController: UIAlertController {

    init() {
        super.init(title: "Are you sure you would like to reset your password?",message: "",preferredStyle: .alert)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
}
```

What is wierd is that I get this error Must call a designated initializer of the superclass 'UIAlertController' in xcode.
This is the init from UIAlertController

```
init(title: String?, 
         message: String?, 
  preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style)
```

I am not sure what is producing this error in xcode any help would be great.

Comment: Please note that `UIAlertController` isn't open API and any subclassing isn't allowed.

Comment: If you can't do that what is the best way to keep my code DRY if I plan on using this Alert accross the app